# How do you get text from dynamically created QLineEdit in a QToolBox?

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit, qgridlayout, qtoolbox

I am trying to make a variable number of pages on a QToolbox with a set number of QLineEdit fields. The number of pages and their names is determined by a vector of strings. Each page of the QToolbox has two QLineEdits. After the fillToolbox function is called, the printExtractedData function is called. As stated in the name I am just looking to print the std::string form of the data.

```
void fillToolbox(vector <string> toolboxLabels){
    QLineEdit *l1, *l2;
    QGridLayout *gridLayout;
    for (int i = 0; i < numEntries; i++)
    {
        gridLayout = new QGridLayout;
        l1 = new QLineEdit;
        l2 = new QLineEdit;
        QFrame *frm = new QFrame;
        QLabel *l1Label = new QLabel("Field 1:");
        QLabel *l2Label = new QLabel("Field 2:");
        gridLayout->addWidget(l1Label, 0, 0);
        gridLayout->addWidget(l1, 0, 1);
        gridLayout->addWidget(l2Label, 1, 0);
        gridLayout->addWidget(l2, 1, 1);
        frm->setLayout(gridLayout);
        ui.myToolBox->addItem(frm, QString(toolboxLabels[i].c_str()));
    }
}
```

User adds input to LineEdit fields.

```
void printExtractedData() {
    int numPages = ui.myToolBox->count();
    cout << numPages << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < numPages; i++)
    {
        string key = ui.myToolBox->itemText(i).toLocal8Bit().constData();
        if (QWidget* wg = qobject_cast<QWidget*>(ui.myToolBox->widget(i))) {
            QLayout *layout = wg->layout();
            for (int j = 0; j < layout->count(); j++)
            {
                if (QLineEdit* le = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(layout->itemAt(j)->widget())) {
                    string text = le->text().toLocal8Bit().constData();
                    cout << le <<endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I insert a two element list, I receive the output:
2
00000245E5A77260
00000245E5A76FE0
00000245E5A0A510
00000245E5B17540

The desired result is a printed string of the content from the QLineEdit fields.
Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The simplest solution is to make the QLineEdit or containers of QLineEdit class members

Answer (score 0):

Just realized I am printing le instead of text. I should have been more careful. That is the only problem.